# Run angularjs front-end web app on codenvy

Tags: angularjs, eclipse-che, codenvy

How do I run an angularjs front-end web app on codenvy? The app uses angular-route.js for routing between pages. I have tried using the preview function, but that one seems to not work due to the routing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a workspace which has a web server like apache httpd installed. For how to do that see [How do you install an apache server (httpd) on codenvy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012445/how-do-you-install-an-apache-server-httpd-on-codenvy)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is to unbound the app from localhost, i.e. use host as 0.0.0.0