# How do you install an apache server (httpd) on codenvy?

Tags: apache, docker, codenvy

I would like to have a simple httpd server on my codenvy machine in order to run a front-end web app. How do I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a workspace with the template "php-default", then a php project. Try run, access the url the "start apache" gave you, and it should work ! I got a running app in less than 3 minutes.

Comment: Ok, this solution worked, although I think it is a bit overkill to use a PHP template just to get an Apache HTTP server. These are the steps I took: 1) Create workspace using the PHP template. 2) Imported my git project (not selected project type PHP). 3) Selecting the index.html file in the project browser. 4) Clicking the run button and selecting "Start apache". 5) Clicking the preview URL which is posted in the console.

Comment: Yeah i know my answer was a bit more than you asked, but it's the fastest way. If you want i can tell you how to install httpd, open firewall if there is one, ... But you might be confronted to permissions issues, and you'd lose half an hour, or more if you are not used to this :)

Comment: Ok, maybe you could give some starting point for doing it in a more clean way. I guess you would start with a blank template? How would you go about installing httpd?

Comment: The step i followed are the following : 
- cat /etc/lsb-release #to check the current version of the os, wich is Ubuntu Xenial 16.04
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install apache2 #install httpd server
- service apache2 status #should not be running
- sudo service apache2 start #run the server
- service apache2 status #to check if its running

Now we arrive at the point where we have a server but we don't know where to connect to it since codenvy did not give you a domain cause it's a blank project.

Comment: To fix it, go to "Workspaces", chose your current workspace, go to "servers", and add a server with port "80" and http as protocol. Save, this will reboot the machine, then you just have to rerun apache2, and pick the url in your server list, and you are good to go.